# Querying Badges Table in data.stackexchange

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

I can get names of all badges using following query in http://data.stackexchange.com/.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Badges
```

I need to apply a filter on the query to list only the gold badges. How can I write the query?

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148147/can-we-expose-class-for-badges-in-data-explorer.

Answer (score 4):

I went looking for this after [you asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148117/badge-that-is-achieved-by-most-number-of-people), and from looking at the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/162704) there doesn't seem to be an easy way to query for badges per class. The badges table schema is:

> ### Badges
>
> - Id
> - UserId, e.g.: "420"
> - Name, e.g.: "Teacher"
> - Date, e.g.: "2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"

Since you are only interested in gold badges, and [there aren't that many of them](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold), the simple solution would be to hardcode their IDs in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't

If you want a distinct list of the gold badges its available here : https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold